# Eloquent Laravel , Superior and Subordinate relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a project in laravel ,
It is an online library in which there can be three types of users , superAdmin
writersAdmin and writers,

I have already created the roles and permissions successfully
but i want to have superiors and subordinates kind of relationship in the users table

for example , the writersAdmin can have multiple writers that work for him,

is it possible to do so in the users table only or do i have to create other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved only in the user table.

for example, add superior_id column, and  the save superior's id.
And, add the following code to the user model.

```
class User extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'users';
public $timestamps = false;

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'superior_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('User', 'superior_id');
}
}
```

How to use

```
User::with('parent')->find(1);
User::with('children')->find(1);
```

but, if there is more than one superiors in the user, can not be achieved in this method.
In that case, I recommend you to create other table.